# How can I show Active Admin filters depending of controller params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I need to do something like this:

```rb
filter :name, if: proc { params[:foo] == 'bar' }
```

Or even better do something like this:

```rb
if params[:foo] == 'bar'
  filter :name
end
```

Probably it does not make any sense trying to access URL params outside a controller block. However to give you some context I have two index pages (like table and grid) and need to show some filters in the table one but not in the grid one. The way I can tell it's rendering one or the other is checking the `as` parameter.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I came up with. Not sure if this is the best way but it works.

```rb
before_filter :only => :index do
  @as = params[:as]
end

filter :name, if: proc { @as == 'grid' }

# This does not work
if @as == 'grid'
  filter :name
end
```